# Unable to save uploaded image to database in Hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await, hapi.js

I want to save the uploaded photo in mongodb using hapi.js. But I can upload the photo in the uploads folder but I haven't been able to save that on the database. This is the code:

```
   server.route({
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/upload',
            config: {
                    payload: {
                        output: "stream",
                        parse: true,
                        allow: "multipart/form-data",
                        maxBytes: 2 * 1000 * 1000
                    }
                },

                  handler: async (req, h) => {

                    const response1 = handleFileUpload(req.payload.image);
                    console.log(response1);
                    return response1;

                  }
         });
const handleFileUpload = file => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const filename = file.hapi.filename
      const data = file._data

      fs.writeFile(`./uploads/${filename}`, data, err => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        }
        resolve({
          message: 'Upload successfully!',
          imageUrl: `${server.info.uri}/uploads/${filename}`
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

As it sends the response message and imageUrl. I've to save that imageurl on the db but I dont know how to access that from the promise return. I'm very new to promise.
this is my model schema:

```
const stuSchema = new Schema({
    image : String,
});
```

html:

```
   <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <label for="image">Image Upoahhd</label>
            <input name="image" type="file" required >

            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
```

I dont know how i will save the value of req.payload.image to the database. I wanted to do it like this on the **handler** method:

```
const user = new User (imageUrl);
const sav = user.save();
return h.response(sav)
```

But I wanted to write them on the resolver function but it accepts objects

Comment: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/handling-file-uploads-with-hapi-js https://medium.com/today-i-learned-chai/how-to-upload-files-with-node-js-hapi-js-c788b5c8586a

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: i mean I've to return the response of the saved values to database but i'm already returning promise here so how i'm supposed to return the input values to save that on db . where should i write this `user.save()` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `await` with the `handleFileUpload` function to get the data from the `Promise` object and then underneath you can use `save()` function to create document inside the database.

```
handler: async (req, reply) => {
  try {
    const { imageUrl } = await handleFileUpload(req.payload.image);
    const user = new User ({ image: imageUrl });
    const result = user.save();
    return ({ message: 'Saved Successfully' });
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}

const handleFileUpload = file => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const filename = file.hapi.filename;
    const data = file._data;

    return fs.writeFile(`./uploads/${filename}`, data, err => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err)
      }
      return resolve({
        message: "Upload successfully!",
        imageUrl: `${server.info.uri}/uploads/${filename}`
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: only some id's is saved into database but no imageUrl is going to the database. And I've edited `return reply({ message: 'Saved Successfully' })` into this  `return reply.response(sav)`  as per hapi new version

Comment: @InsaneDA Updated my answer. You just need to save with the same field `image`.

Comment: it worked thanks. But one fixing to your code `return reply({ message: 'Saved Successfully' })` it's going to give a `TypeError reply is not a function`. With the new API you don't  have to use the response toolkit to return text response , you can simply return the text from the handler.